# Embed Object in Specific Cell In Table in a Word Document Using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

As of now I can only embed the document through this code:

```
Dim wordDoc as word.document
wordDoc.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject Filename:="C:/Doc.doc", Linktofile:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconLabel:="Sample"
```

The problem is I want to embed the object to specific cells in a table. What's happening is it inserts to the first cell only. I;v tried to searched but with no luck.
I'm a newbie in VBA so please help me. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be something like:

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(2).Cells(2).Range.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject Filename:="C:/Doc.doc", Linktofile:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconLabel:="Sample"
```